# Post request from Backbone client to NodeJS service

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, express

Somehow I am not able to send data from Backbone model to NodeJS service.

**Backbone Model**

```
var Money = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/sendCoins',
    defaults: {
        fromAddress: "",
        toAddress: "",
        amount: ""
    },
    transferMoney: function(req, resp) {
        //get field values
        console.log(req.fromAddress); //prints fine
        this.save();
    }
});

var transferMoney = new Money();
```

**Node JS service**

```
var app = express();
    app.listen(3000);
    app.use(express.json());

app.use(function (req, res, next) {

    // Website you wish to allow to connect
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    // Request methods you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

    // Request headers you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

    // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
    // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

    // Pass to next layer of middleware
    next();
});


app.post('/sendCoins', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body.toAddress);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body));
    console.log(req.body.amount);
});
```

When I post the request from backbone view `console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body));` prints `{"fromAddress":"","toAddress":"","amount":""}`.

Comment: Your backbone model is empty and it sends the defaults you provided, I don't understand what isn't working for you.

Comment: I think you're not using express.bodyParser()

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned by M Omary, you need to use the body parser in order to have access to `req.body`. Add the following code above `app.post`  to see if it works:

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
```